# Doctrine, ignore some fields to persist and null

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

given a user:

```
id, name, password
```

so I want to modify him, and set a name to it. But then if I persists, his password will be rewritten (set to empty), even though I didnt set it. But here is the `nullable=true` annotation! Right now it seems to work - but this way its impossible to persist if I want to set it `null` itself. Then how?

Comment: are you updating the user via forms?

Comment: yea, why does it matter?

Comment: If you are using the same form for both add/modify, just process the password if it has changed else ignore it. I would do this by making the password field unmapped and if that field is present the set it to the user password field.

Answer (score 1):

in the password field in form add the argument mapped => false do the Doctrine will not be considered as an entity field in the moment of form validation.

```
->add('password', 'password', array(
   'mapped' => false
))
```